# Telegram bot (with add new admin rights) can't promote new admins or change custom title of existing ones. Why?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Am writing my first telegram bot for group chats with `python-telegram-bot` package. And faced an issue.

Bot with exactly same rights (all of them, incl. adding new admins)

1. in my test groups (few users) - can promote new admins and change their custom title, no problem, but
2. in larger group chat (300+ users) - fails to promote new admins & assign custom titles, and gets `telegram.error.BadRequest: Chat_admin_required` and `telegram.error.BadRequest: Not enough rights to change custom title of the user` errors.

Using `bot.promoteChatMember` to promote new admins, and `bot.set_chat_administrator_custom_title` to set custom titles.

Same bot, same rights, all looks same.

What can be an issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you given your bot the permission to add new admins? You should manually do it from group administrators' section.

Comment: Yes I did. Bot has all admin rights (incl adding new admins).

Answer (score 1):

To change custom title, user has to be promoted by the bot itself. Bot can not change titles for users promoted by others.

Check `get_chat_administrators` method. For each user it will return `can_be_edited` flat which indicates whenever is bot capable for modifying this user.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is that:
400 CHAT_ADMIN_REQUIRED You must be an admin in this chat to do this